# nginx redirect subdomain to a url path

Tags: webserver, nginx, cname

I have a requirement where I need to point `xyz.tld` to `abc.def.tld`. Additionally I would have to internally rewrite/redirect `abc.def.tld` to `def.tld/abc`. So the final result here I intend is when I visit `xyz.tld`, it should render contents of `def.tld/abc` without URL change. What is the idle way of achieving this? I have tried proxy_pass but when I do proxy pass, some static files (js files) at the root folder get messed up. Here is what I tried. Additionally I am not able to point xyz.tld to abc.def.tld using CNAME (as it resolves to IP).

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~(?<subdomain>\w+)\.def\.tld;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$subdomain$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  # pass the host header - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

        proxy_http_version 1.1;  # recommended with keepalive connections - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version

        # WebSocket proxying - from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Will a permanent redirect help? But if I do this, can I still point xyz.tld to abc.def.tld?